# Save password hash only when password is present

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a form where users can create a room with an optional password field. I want to save the password only if the password field contains something ( is not empty). I have hash middleware that hash the password before saving it to mongodb. Even if the password field is empty it is saving a hash value. I tried to add a condition to check if there is a value only then to proceed with the hashing but this does not seem to work.

Here is my post :

```
exports.postCreateRooms = function(req, res, next) {
req.assert('workspace', 'Please enter a board name').notEmpty();
var errors = req.validationErrors();
var enableVideo;
if (errors) {
req.flash('errors', errors);
return res.redirect('/dashboard');
}
var url = uuid.v4();


var room = new Room({
roomUrl: url,
roomName: req.body.workspace,
owner:req.user._id,
      ownerEmail:req.user.email,
dateCreated: Date(),
      lastUpdated: Date(),
      users: [req.user._id]
});
if (req.body.password != ''){
room.password = req.body.password;
}

room.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
res.redirect('/board='+room.roomUrl);
});

};
```

here is my hash middleware :

```
roomSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var room = this;


if(room.password){

bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
if (err) {
  return next(err);
}

 bcrypt.hash(room.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
  room.password = hash;
  next();
});
 });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you have the check in place?

From what I can see, you need a next() call outside of your if block in the middleware, so it knows to proceed even if there isn't a password specified.

It would look like

```
roomSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var room = this;

  if(room.password){
    return bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      bcrypt.hash(room.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        room.password = hash;
        next();
      });
    });
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: You need to add a `return` in front of the `bcrypt.genSalt()` call, otherwise you will face a double callback issue.

Comment: It was hanging...Adding next works but now it is not going through the if function and thus not hashing the password.

Comment: Adding return in front of the brcyp.genSalt() call did the trick! Thanks @gyamana

Comment: Oh of course, my bad. Thanks for pointing it out @gyamana. Updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Update (2017) - only 3 parameters for bcrypt.hash